# Getting multiple OHLCV candles with API with one request

Tags: api, exchange-rate

i don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but i haven't found a proper one to do so, so here we go :

I wanna get only the LAST OHLCV candle from multiple markets with the cryptocompare api using only one request. Is that possible ?

For example : I can get multiple coin prices using only one request by doing this : https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=NXT,OK,XRP,LTC,1ST,PAY,XVG,XLM,BCH&tsyms=BTC&e=Bittrex

I want to do the same thing, but getting the last OHLCV (1 min, 5 min, 15 min...etc) instead. Is that possible ? If it is, can someone explain me how to do it ? If cryptocompare does not support this, is there any other API that allow me to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [ClueDex](https://www.cluedex.com/api). By default, all Bittrex markets are returned in a single query. You can specify how many candle data you wish to get with the "periodqty" parameter. In your case, you make periodqty equal to 1 for the last period.

Additionally, you can create your own period, you aren't limited to the standard periods. For example, if you wanted 30-second periods, you just specify the "period" parameter as 30S.

If you had a need to go back in time Cluedex also has the capability to do that, too.

The only drawback is, if it even is one, is that it's not a free API, it's premium. However, the prices are reasonable and the data isn't cached.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can create your own period, you aren't limited to the standard periods. For example, if you wanted 30-second periods, you just specify the "period" parameter as 30S.

If you had a need to go back in time Cluedex also has the capability to do that, too